# None type for non-slot variable in Tensorflow2 Adabound implementation

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use this tensorflow2 adabound optimizer adaptation and am getting error that one of my non slot variables is None on line 112 of the _resource_apply_dense function

repo is here- https://github.com/taki0112/AdaBound-Tensorflow

I see on line 59 in the _create_slots function, that beta1_power is created and i verify that is created by printing

```
self._get_non_slot_variable("beta1_power", graph=graph)
```

However if i try to print this variable prior to line 112 i see that it is None

I don't see anywhere in the code it would be getting set back to None.

Comment: So it looks like eager execution is somehow being turned off by the time it reached the other function. Not sure why though.